# Recursively replacing elements in XSLT

Tags: xslt, recursion

I need to replace the `<tref>` element with other tags from elsewhere in my document. For example, I have:

```
<tref id="57236"/>
```

and

```
<Topic>
    <ID>57236</ID>
    <Text>
        <p id="4">
            <cs id="56792">1090-189-01 </cs>
            <href id="57237">
                  <cs id="56792">Document Name</cs>
            </href>
        </p>
    </Text>
</Topic>
```

Obtaining the following is not a problem:

```
<p id="4">
    <cs id="56792">1090-189-01 </cs>
    <href id="57237">
        <cs id="56792">Document Name</cs>
    </href>
</p>
```

With this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tref">
    <xsl:variable name="NodeID"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//Topic[ID = $NodeID]/Text/p/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

What I cannot do is replacing trefs nested into other trefs. For example, consider the following:

```
<tref id="57236"/>
```

and:

```
<Topic>
    <ID>57236</ID>
    <Text>
        <p id="251">
            <tref id="37287"/>
        </p>
    </Text>
</Topic>
```

My stylesheet duly replaces the tref with the content of the  tag - which also contains a tref:

```
<p id="251">
    <tref id="37287"/>
</p>
```

My current solution is to call `<xsl:template match="tref">` from two different stylesheets. It does the job, but it is not very elegant, and what if trefs are nested at an even deeper level? And recursion is the bread and butter of XSLT.

Is there a solution to recursively replace all trefs as in XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `xsl:copy-of`, use `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Topic[ID = $NodeID]/Text/p/node()"/>
```

Or, to eliminate the use of the varianle

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Topic[ID = current()/@id]/Text/p/node()"/>
```

Note you can make use of an `xsl:key` to look-up the `Topic` elements

```
<xsl:key name="topic" match="Topic" use="ID" />
```

Then you can write this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('topic', @id)/Text/p/node()"/>
```

Be wary of infinite recursion if you have a `tref` referring to a `Topic` that is an ancestor of it.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much for your answer.

I applied your snippets #1 and #2, and it works.

I will have to ponder about your snippets #3 and #4 since I am not familiar with xsl:key.

Comment: There was minor error in snippet 4, which I have now corrected, by the way.  Learning about xsl:key would be recommended as it is a very useful command, especially if you have ever to do grouping in XSLT 1.0.